# The text in the span element and the border length of the span do not equal

Tags: html, css

```css
.text{
  max-width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">dsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsl</span>
```

When the text is very long, the bottom border is slightly wider than the text.
Is there any solution to make both strictly the same length?

[image: goal]

I think it may be caused by not being able to accommodate the truncated first character.

Comment: hello, what makes you think that the ellipsis dots are not text and should be standing outside the box ? May be you should consider using text-decoration? `text-decoration:underline 1px dotted;` instead border on the box itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `text-decoration` property doesn't underline the entire text. It's not very practical to combine it with `text-overflow`. However, undoubtedly, character truncation with JavaScript is the perfect solution... `text-decoration` is the second-best option... while `text-overflow` is quite unusable in such cases due to the continuous right-side spacing.

Answer (score 0):

### Why does it work like that?

[image]

> **Important!**
>
> For a better demonstration of the example, I have set the base font size to 50px!

It is noticeable that the required width of the box is set to 200px, however, with the use of `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, it cuts off enough characters for the 3 dots to fit. Nevertheless, the characters have different widths. It is worth considering a font type where the sizes of the characters are consistent.

### Solution # 1 (Better than with `text-overflow`)

Use JavaScript. Pre-determine the total number of characters you want to see... Keep that amount and add three dots at the end of the text. This way, you won't manipulate the text inside the box, and the text will perfectly match the width of the box, preventing it from overflowing the boundaries.

```js
const charCount = 6
const textElements = document.querySelectorAll('.solution')

textElements.forEach(textElement => {
  textElement.textContent = `${textElement.textContent.substring(0, charCount)}...`
})
```

```css
.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}

.solution {
  font-size: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="text">dsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsl</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="solution">dsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsl</span>
</div>
```

### Solution # 2 (Alternative)

**-- It's quite a "home-made" solution.

-- I would stick with the first one as there is no better option.**

Use `font-family: monospace;` as default or you can choose a font where each character has the same width.

> It is important to note that in monospace styles, the space occupied by the ellipsis (three dots) typically equals the space occupied by one character exactly.

If you are using a monospace style, you know the width of one character. The text box should be sized in a way that no empty space is left. For example, if one character is `19px` wide and you want to display `10 characters`, when setting a maximum width of `200px`, `19 * 10 = 190`, leaving `10px of empty space`... This is what causes the empty space in my example, even with monospace characters.

```css
.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}

.solution {
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="text">dsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsl</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="text solution">dsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsl</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

To ensure that the border length matches the text length exactly, you can make use of a container element with relative positioning. By adding a pseudo-element to the container with an absolute position, you can achieve the desired effect. Here's an updated version of your code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">dsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsldsagjadsl</span>
</div>
```

In this updated code, the `.container` element acts as a wrapper around the `.text` element. The `::after` pseudo-element is added to the container, and it creates a border that matches the width of the text, even when it's truncated.

This way, the border will always be the same length as the visible text, regardless of whether it's truncated or not.

Comment: I try you method but the border is still a little longer than the text's length

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.